# Update tables/fields in database - Doctrine 2 and Codeigniter 2

Tags: codeigniter, orm, doctrine, doctrine-orm, codeigniter-2

I have generated `Entities` files, `Proxies` files and `Tables/fields` in database via `.yml` file schema. I would like to add one more field in schema file.

How can I regenerate `Entities`, `Proxies` and MySQL `tables/fields` via command line tool without dropping tables and deleting all records?

I tried with these and does not work (I am getting error):

- `./doctrine orm:schema-tool:create`
- `./doctrine orm:schema:tool:update`

What did I miss?

Comment: +1 for an issue I keep running into also. Eager to hear if there's a good way to re-generate when there's existing records and table structure has been altered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution:

With this command `orm:schema-tool:update --force` you add/remove/update fields in database without dropping all records. But firstly you need to change `YAML` file **and** `Entity class`.